# How can you bypass the pipeline and release to a specific environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a release to three environments, Dev, QA, Production, and working through failures, mainly IIS Application errors.

Right now, I'm trying to get my QA environment setup.  Unfortunately it is a lot of trial and error to get the release to pass.  When it fails, I have to go edit the release, edit my tasks for the QA environment, then start a release all over.

My problem is, I'm just trying to get this setup, these aren't "real" releases.  However I'm wasting time after each configuration change having it deploy code to my "Dev" environment.  I already know those steps work.

Is there a way I can skip an environment, and select a specific environment I want it to release code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel said that you can choose the environments which you want to deploy manually when start a release.

[image]

You also can set Manual only for the environment directly:

[image]

You also can enable Artifact filters with specific tags or branch (git), then just the artifact meet the filters, the release can deploy to this environment.

[image]

Comment: Is there a recommended way to do this using new YAML Az Pipelines and Environments?

Answer (score 2):

When you start a release you're presented with a list of all of the environments and their deployment conditions. Simple set all of the environments to "Manual". Then when you create the release, you can choose the environment to which you wish to deploy from the "Deploy" menu.